# Implementing compareTo() in an abstract class

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I have an abstract class in my application (let's call it `BaseRule`).
`BaseRule` implements the `Comparable` interface, and contains an abstract method signature `public abstract int getExecOrder()`.

Within the `BaseRule` implementation of the `compareTo()` method in the `BaseRule` class, the return value of `getExecOrder()` is used to compare the objects.

At present, I have 3 concrete implementations of the `BaseRule` class, each of which implement the `getExecOrder()` method

The ultimate purpose of having the `BaseRule` class implement the `Comparable` interface is that a Collection of `BaseRule` objects are passed to a utility that needs to sort these objects to ensure that they are executed in the proper order.

In this case, execution order only matters at the Class level, meaning that every `BaseRuleA` must be executed before any `BaseRuleB` is executed, but every `BaseRuleB` is effectively 'equal' to every other `BaseRuleB`, so the order that those `BaseRuleB` objects are processed does not matter

My question is, is there a better way to handle comparing these objects as opposed to using (what I came up with) a `getExecOrder()` method ?

Right now, I only have 3 concrete implementations of `BaseRule` so it was easy enough to just assign return values of 1,2,3 to those `getExecOrder()` method calls, but if another developer adds a new `BaseRule` implementation, they would have to scan all the existing implementations, and (possibly) update those return values in all of the classes to accommodate the new `BaseRule`.

Any ideas on a better implementation?

Comment: An idea is not handle the order stuff in the code level, but to let the class dependent on them to decide. You could made them all present a field like `order`, init it in the constructor. So in the class where these  `BaseRuleA`s and `BaseRuleB`s  get instanced and chained to cope together, you could arrange the order of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're talking about the following sort of thing?

```
abstract class BaseRule implements Comparable<BaseRule>
{
    abstract int executionPrecedence();

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final BaseRule that)
    {
        return Integer.compare(this.executionPrecedence(), that.executionPrecedence());
    }
}

class RuleA extends BaseRule
{
    @Override
    int executionPrecedence() { return 0; }
}

class RuleB extends BaseRule
{
    @Override
    int executionPrecedence() { return 1; }
}
```

It seems fairly reasonable. If you're concerned about having to change the values of existing classes in the future then just leave big gaps rather than using contiguous integers.

A = 10000

B = 20000

C = 30000

Now you have 9999 spaces to place future implementations between these ones.

---

Maybe also add a unit test which uses reflection to check that no two implementations share the same precedence.

Comment: yes, your interpretation is exactly what I have. I like the idea of the unit test. I'll have to read up on how to get all the concrete implementations of my BaseRule with reflection. Thank You!

Comment: actually, in trying to implement the unit test, the problem is going to be that each of the concrete implementations have different constructors. the BaseRule class constructor accepts a single string, but the concrete implementations have different constructors. I may not be able to do the unit tests.

Comment: @user1154644 It's possible. You just have to use reflection to invent some arguments. If we assume that for any Object parameter that we can just use null, then we only need to worry about primitives. Maybe zero for every numeric value, false for boolean etc. [Here is an example](https://ideone.com/oMRzBh) where I use reflection to call a constructor with a random selection of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly think your proposed implementation is the best way to go about this. Definitely add some comments to the abstract `getExecOrder()` so that future developers know exactly what their implementation of it is supposed to do.